# How to force https using friendly url with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Tags: php, apache, friendly-url

folks!

I have an PHP application runing on Apache2 in localhost. The system uses friendly URL from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myapp.localhost/$1 [R=permanent]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If I comment lines 3 and 4, the system run ok. If I use the code as I show you, he write URL as https://myapp.localhost/index.php?/ where it needs to write https://myapp.localhost/. SSL Certified it's ok.

Images and archives can't be found with this configuration, but without lines 3 and 4 and using https manually it's showed.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Try commenting out your rewrite rule on line 6: `# RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]` it appears to serve no purpose.

Comment: Good afternoon, Mr @Martin. I try and returns https://myapp.localhost/index.php?/. Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: Mr. Martin, eu também testei este método aqui, mas sem sucesso: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/123736/how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-https-with-seo-friendly-url-using-apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the last message i answer in portuguese, Mr. @Martin.

Maybe the problem was use more than one tutorial. After so much  searchs. I understand: it was necessary delete some lines of code at  /etc/apache2/sites-available/bigpecasnew-localhost-ssl.conf and add this lines at `<Directory /home/user/site>SSLOptions +StdEnvVars</Directory>` as I read in
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-18-04.

After I change my code on .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So that works.

Thank you for your cooperation.